# Writing data into Excel-Sheet sequentially using openpyxl isn't working

Tags: python, excel, pandas, database, openpyxl

I'm trying to read data from a sheet, have that data used as a variable in a function and finally have the output written into the sheet. I've managed get the first half of this to work but am unable to write the output into the sheet:

```py
column_name = 'username'
column_name2 = 'hashtags'

for column_cell in sheet.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):
    if column_cell[0].value == column_name:
        B = 0
        for data in column_cell[1:]:
            htag = data.value
            h = Hashtag.from_name(l.context, htag)
            if column_cell[0].value == column_name2:
                C = 0
                for cell in column_cell[1:]:
                    cell.value = h.mediacount
                    book.save('alpha list test.xlsx')
```

The code runs indefinitely without any errors but without doing anything to the sheet so it's hard to figure out where I'm going wrong.

I tried adding `print(h.mediacount)` before python `if column_cell[0].value == column_name2:` and it loops through that flawlessly so I believe it must be an issue with the code underneath and writing to the workbook.

Comment: Why do you want to save the workbook after each cell? If you're not seeing anything happening, it's likely the condition is never met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you are trying to get the hashtag for each username in a column, then get the associated mediacount and write this value into the rows for column 'hashtags'. I think you are making things more complicated than they need to be. The problems with your code are as follows:

```
column_name = 'username'
column_name2 = 'hashtags'

for column_cell in sheet.iter_cols(1, sheet.max_column):
    if column_cell[0].value == column_name:
    # we are now inside col with 'username' as header
    
        B = 0
        for data in column_cell[1:]:
            htag = data.value
            h = Hashtag.from_name(l.context, htag)
            
    # now you are trying to access col 'hashtags', but the below if statement
    # will never be TRUE, since we are INSIDE col 'username'
    
            if column_cell[0].value == column_name2:
            
    # i.e. the following block is unreachable. But even if we WERE to reach it, 
    # it won't do what you want. This would populate the ENTIRE range with 
    # 'h.mediacount' for username1, then overwrite it for username2, etc.
    # at the end you would simple have n rows with h.mediacount for your last
    # username. This is clearly not what you want.
    
                C = 0
                for cell in column_cell[1:]:
                    cell.value = h.mediacount
                    
    # finally, you need to unindent 'book.save()'. Again, we are never
    # reaching this line, but if we WERE to reach it, you would be saving
    # your wb countless times, since it is part of the nested for loop
    
                    book.save('alpha list test.xlsx')
```

Suggested solution. Find the col with 'username' as header. Only loop through this col (`sheet[col][1:]`), get the hashtag and mediacount, and then write the value into the appropriate row for col with 'hashtags'. This should work, I think:

```
import openpyxl

# import helper function to get column letter
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

from instaloader import Hashtag, Instaloader

filename = "wb.xlsx"

book = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = book['Sheet1']

l = Instaloader()

column_name = 'username'
column_name2 = 'hashtags'

# get a list of all your headers
headers = [cell.value for cell in sheet[1]]

# find 'username' in headers and get col letter
col = get_column_letter(headers.index(column_name)+1)

# get col index for 'hashtags'
col2 = headers.index(column_name2)+1

# loop through usernames
for cell in sheet[col][1:]:
    htag = cell.value
    h = Hashtag.from_name(l.context, htag)
    
    # populate rows in col 'hashtags'
    sheet.cell(cell.row,col2).value = h.mediacount

# AFTER the loop, save your wb
book.save('alpha list test.xlsx')
```